# How to reuse database controllers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to reuse my controllers which handle database operations. I'm bit struggling with structuring my application. Here's what I have:

**server.js**

```
var apiController = require('./controllers/api');

router.get('/cars', function (req, res) {
    // get all cars from DB and render view

    apiController.getCars().then(function (cars) {
        res.render('index', {cars: cars});
    });
});

router.get('/api/cars', function (req, res) {
    // get all cars from DB and return JSON

    apiController.getCars().then(function (cars) {
        res.json(cars);
    });
});
```

**controllers/api.js**

```
module.exports = {

    getCars: function () {
        db.collection('cars').find().toArray( function (err, cars) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return cars;
        });
    },

    // tried also something like this but this doesn't really work 
    // for my use case because I don't want to attach any particular
    // res to the function
    getCars: function (req, res, next) {
        db.collection('cars').find().toArray( function (err, cars) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(cars);
        });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is that you expect promises as return in server.js while you use callbacks in the controller. I suggest you change your function getCars to return a Promise. Don't know what ODM/ORM you're using but it might look like something like this:

```
getCars: function () {
    return db.collection('cars').find();
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are right, I'm expecting promise in server.js, that's why it didn't work. Is using promises the standard way to handle DB controller - router relation in express? I'm basically looking for the correct pattern, I'm not necessarily attached to promises.

Comment: One downside to this approach would be that I'd have to do error handling for getCars in each router, right?

Comment: callbacks are the old way to handle async in JavaScript. Promises the new. So I would suggest you'll use Promises if you dont feel too stungly about it.

Comment: For structure, have a look at an example app I've created: https://github.com/RobinGulbrandsen/react-blog/tree/master/server/src The Controllers only job is to validate and return correct statuses while Repository code does the db stuff

Comment: Different routes might want to return different status codes to the client based on authentication or state..

Answer (score 0):

```
server.js

var apiController = require('./controllers/api');
    router.get('/cars', apiController.getCars);



controllers/api.js

    function getCarsAsync(req, res, next){
         db.collection('cars').find().then(function(carsData){
            if(carsData){
               return res.send(carsData);
            }
            else{
                return res.status(401).send('User is not authorized');
            }
         }).catch(function(err){
            return next(err);
         });
    }

    module.exports = { 
        getCars: getCarsAsync
   };
```

Comment: You were not using promise correctly. One good structure is to just write function definitions in module.exports like this
module.exports = { getCars : getCarsAsync}
and write all the logic in getCarsAsync function

Comment: How would you clean up the error message from the database with this solution? Lets say you want to give a 400 if you attempt to add a new row to a table where there is a unique contraint? Wont your solution return a general 500? I suggest that his HttpStatus handling is done outside the database function so it can be reused

Comment: @R.Gulbrandsen You will practically have 3 - 4 different types of error codes. What you can do is: Use `next ` third parameter of route function and configure express to have a custom middleware to handle `next()`. Then you will pass error message as `next({"error": "missing", "description": "some error message"})` the middleware should map missing to 404 and hence api will get 404 as status with appropriate error message.

Comment: Check my updated answer. There are many ways to send response and error back to caller i have used few

Answer (score 0):

server.js

```
var apiController = require('./controllers/api');
router.get('/cars', function (req, res) {
    apiController.get('cars').then(function (cars) {
        res.render('index', {cars: cars});
    });
});

router.get('/api/cars', function (req, res) {
    apiController.get('cars').then(function (cars) {
        res.json(cars);
    });
});
```

controllers/api.js

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
module.exports = {
  get: function (modelName) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      return db.collection(modelName).find().toArray(function(err, models){
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        else {
          return resolve(models);
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
```